# ¿Cómo convertir una cadena en un array de elementos?

Tags: javascript

He estado intentando, pero lo que me gustaría hacer es que los argumentos se vuelvan un array.

```
let argumentos = "1, 2, 4, 3, 6"
```

Espero que se convierta en algo así

```
[1, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 6):

Puedes hacer uso del `split` para separar los elementos por `,` pero antes eliminara los espacio con la función `replace`

```js
const argumentos = "1, 2, 4, 3, 6"
const resultado = argumentos.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
console.log(resultado);

// Si necesitas que tu array sean de tipo numero, puedes parsearlos

console.log(resultado.map(x => parseInt(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let args = "1, 2, 4, 3, 6";
args = args.split(', ');
```

Los puedes convertir de vuelta a array con:

```
args = args.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedes convertir el *CSV* a matriz de datos usando el método **split**, obteniendo un *array* de *strings*.
Después conviertes cada *string* (usando el método **map**) a número aplicandoles la función **Number** (este ignorará los espacios en blanco del *string*).
Por ejemplo:

```js
let argumentos = "1, 2, 4, 3, 6";

var numeros = argumentos.split(',').map(Number);
console.log(numeros);
```

Answer (score -2):

Intenta con un `split()`, te dejo un enlace a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split)

```
let array = argumentos.split(",");
```